# how to apply your own shell in the system

Tags: shell

At the moment, I am developing my shell on Rust, and so I have completed the most important functionality, but I had the biggest problem how to apply it at the system level, for example, to derive a list of available shells, I need to write

```
$ chsh -l
```

How can I add my shell to this list?

Comment: `/etc/shells` ??

Comment: First, research `man chsh`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't watch, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man chsh`:

```
   -l, --list-shells
       Print the list of shells listed in /etc/shells and exit.
```

> How can I add my shell to this list?

You would add the path to excuteble in /etc/shells. See `man 5 shells`.